Are MySQL memory calculators accurate for complex workloads?
I recently used the MySQL Memory Calculator to optimize the configuration of my database. While the tool provides suggested values for settings like innodb_buffer_pool_size and query_cache_size, I’m noticing discrepancies between the recommendations and my database's actual performance.
For example:

The recommended innodb_buffer_pool_size resulted in frequent swapping, leading to high latency under heavy workloads.
The calculated tmp_table_size seems too low, causing an increase in on-disk temporary tables during complex queries.
I’m wondering:


How reliable are these calculators for dynamic or highly variable workloads?
Should such recommendations always be cross-checked with manual calculations or performance metrics?
What’s the best practice for fine-tuning memory settings in cases where automated tools fall short?
Any guidance or insights into using these tools effectively—or alternative strategies for optimizing MySQL memory—would be greatly appreciated!


I agree with Rick James that so-called memory calculators for MySQL are useless. I often recommend that people delete "MySQLTuner" type scripts and forget they ever existed.
There is no formula for "optimal" tuning. You make changes to handle your specific workload against your data on your servers.
Use observability tools such as Percona Monitoring and Metrics to observe memory usage over time. This will give you some experience with the trend lines and the range of memory usage your database experiences under your application's workload.
Once you have some observability solution in place, then you can watch how memory usage changes as you make tuning changes, or if you make application code changes, or the traffic goes up or down.
If you don't have something to give you that visibility, then you're just making blind guesses.
Of course there are a variety of observability services that are also good for this purpose. Datadog, New Relic, SolarWinds Database Performance Monitor, etc. They all cost way more than you want to spend.
AWS CloudWatch is useless.

In my opinion, memory calculators are not useful for any situation.

I say 70% of available RAM for innodb_buffer_pool_size, with the emphasis on "available".  That is, after other apps are given the room they need.  Also, 70% is too high for less than 4GB of RAM.  Yes, if this setting is too high, thrashing and/or swapping will hurt performance.

Query cache should be turned off in nearly all production systems, especially when clustering is involved.

tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size work together.  But the real fix is to work on the queries -- usually a better (or composite) index helps or a rewrite of the query or rethinking of the data flow.

I recommend using the SlowLog for finding the "worst" queries.  And my in-depth analysis of settings .



I think we can use calculators such as:
Releem MySQL Memory Calculator
Alexander Avchinnikov’s MySQL Memory Calculator
Abhinavbit’s MySQL Memory Calculator
and others to get initial recommendations and then iterate on those values ​​with manual adjustments based on real-world performance from your database.
This hybrid approach combines convenience and precision. Also for complex environments, fine-tuning based on workload-specific data is essential to achieve optimal performance.
